# How do you calculate the retention rate given daily installs and daily active users

Tags: data

Example table

| Date. | Installs | DAU |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13/3/2020 | 150. | 150 |
| 14/3/2020 | 100. | 125 |
| 15/3/2020 | 150. | 200 |
| 16/3/2020 | 100. | 225 |

Comment: please post in stackoverflow . I will answer there. this is data science group.

Comment: Is this asking "what is the definition of retention rate" given such a table, or do you have that definition and are asking how to compute it in, say, pandas?  The former is on topic here, the latter is not (and you would need to provide that definition as well as whether you're using pandas or something else in any post to SO).  cc@amolgoel